# Mac OS Blender 2.9. Some keyboard shortcuts do not work

Tags: osx

I am using Blender 2.9 on a Mac Laptop computer and Desktop. I am noticing the following short cut key's do not work.

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd>/ <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> does not work
2. In the *Shader Editor* short Cut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>T</kbd> does not work]

Is there a fix coming soon?

Comment: You can customize your own shortcuts.

Comment: ctrl-t works, but you need the add-on "node wrangler" to be checked. what do u expect to happen with ctrl+option+c ? you have to always tell, where u r using your short cut because in every view the short cut could mean something totally different